# php Найти все ссылки и заменить им атрибут href

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Нужно найти в html все ссылки и заменить им атрибут href на кастомный текст

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo пример регулярного выражения
https://regex101.com/r/VOpKzB/2